# How to edit binary InfoPlist.strings in Mountain Lion (for Finder to display folders before files)?

Tags: macos, finder, folders, tweaks, binary

The article [Force your Mac to sort folders on top of files (windows style)](http://www.howtogeek.com/67100/force-your-mac-to-put-folders-on-top-of-files-windows-style/), lets the Finder change its sorting order to first show folders and next all files.

This trick doesn't seem to work with Mountain Lion, InfoPlist.strings seems to be a binary file.

Do you know how to edit InfoPlist.strings in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `InfoPlist.strings` file you mention is a binary formatted property list. You can convert and edit these files with developer tools such as [plutil](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/plutil.1.html).

The following article walks through the steps required, [Show folders last in Finder](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2011072120153685).

Answer (score 3):

Download TextWrangler from the Mac App Store. It automatically converts binary strings files and plist files for editing and is a generally good code editor.

Comment: It opens it, but won't let me save it because I'm not a member of the group "wheel". Any idea how to save it back down again?

Comment: Save it to your desktop and copy it over to the original location. You will have to type your password.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Finder, on the menu bar go to 'View', then scroll to 'View Options'.

Arrange by 'Kind', and sort by 'Kind' as in the screenshot, and the folders will be at the top.

[image: Screenshot of view preferences]

Comment: does it work for you ? I don't think it does for me...

Comment: what if i don't want every Finder view ordering the files by Kind?  editing the Finder Infoplist is a much better option as you can sort as desired (ie by Name not Kind).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Xcode, it will open plist files, and display them in a nice editable tree-view.